# Jetpack Compose: react to Slider changed value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a slider that can be either updated by the user using drag/drop, or updated from the server in real-time.

When the user finishes their dragging gesture, I want to send the final value to the server.

My initial attempt is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LightView(
    channel: UiChannel,
    onDimmerChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    val sliderValue = channel....
    Slider(value = sliderValue, onValueChange = onDimmerChanged)
}
```

And the `onDimmerChanged` method comes from my ViewModel, which updates the server value.
It works well, however `onValueChange` is called for each move, which bombards the server with unneeded requests.

I tried to create a custom slider:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LightView(
    channel: UiChannel,
    onDimmerChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    val sliderValue = channel....
    Slider(initialValue = sliderValue, valueSetter = onDimmerChanged)
}

@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { valueSetter(value) }
    )
}
```

It works well on the app side, and the value is only sent once, when the user stops dragging.

However, it fails updating the view when there is an update from the server. I'm guessing this has something to do with `remember`. So I tried without `remember`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {
    var value by mutableStateOf(initialValue)
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { valueSetter(value) }
    )
}
```

This time the view updates correctly when the value is updated by the server, but does not move anymore when the user drags the slider.

I'm sure I'm missing something with state hoisting and all, but I can't figure out what.

**So my final question**: how to create a Slider that can be either updated by the ViewModel, or by the user, and notifies the ViewModel of a new value only when the user finishes dragging?

**EDIT:**

I also tried what @CommonsWare suggested:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LightView(
    channel: UiChannel,
    onDimmerChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    val sliderValue = channel....
    val sliderState = mutableStateOf(sliderValue)
    Slider(state = sliderState, valueSet = { onDimmerChanged(sliderState.value) })
}

@Composable
fun Slider(state: MutableState<Float>, valueSet: () -> Unit) {
    Slider(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { state.value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = valueSet
    )
}
```

And it does not work either. When using drag and drop, `sliderState` is correctly updated, and `onDimmerChanged()` is called with the correct value. But for some reason, when tapping of the sliding (rather than sliding), `valueSet` is called and `sliderState.value` does not contain the correct value. I don't understand where this value comes from.

Comment: `Slider()` probably needs to be passed `State<Float>` instead of `Float`, where your `State<Float>` is a `MutableState<Float>` held somewhere that is shared between your call to `Slider()` and your code for reacting to server responses. The server response would result in an update to that `MutableState<Float>`, triggering recomposition.

Comment: Thx @CommonsWare, it does not seems to work either. See my edit.

Comment: Personally, I have not used `onValueChangeFinished()` yet, so perhaps there is a bug (e.g., `onValueChangeFinished()` called before the final `onValueChange()` call). You might try creating a project that demonstrates the issue and filing an issue. Beyond that, I know that `onValueChange()` works for simple clicks. So, perhaps you could just use that, both to update your `MutableState` and to feed to your viewmodel, applying some debounce logic so the viewmodel only does work after a period of inactivity.

Comment: I tried with a very simple Slider and VM and `onValueChange()` is called before `onValueChangeFinished()`, both with dragging and clicking. So I don't know how to create an issue sadly. I'll look into debouncing too. Thx!

Comment: `onValueChangeFinished` capturing the wrong state value seems to be a bug in the Slider component. My best guess is that it should be using `rememberUpdatedState`, but I'm not sure right now. Please file an issue in the Compose Material component in the issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/components/742043/

Comment: This is a weird bug, pretty hard to track down. When using the delegate for constructing the state (`var sliderProgress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }`), it works. When using destructuring (`val (sliderProgress, setProgress) = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }`) this bug appears. That being said, I tested wrapping `onValueChangeFinished` inside `Slider` with `rememberUpdatedState` and it worked for both cases after.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the original problem with local & server (or viewmodel) states conflicting with eachother:

I solved it for me by detecting **wether or not we are interacting** with the slider:

- if yes, then show and update the *local state value*
- or if not - then *show the viewmodels value*.

As you have said, we should **never** update the viewmodel from `onValueChange` - as this is only for updating the sliders value locally ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Slider(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.material.SliderColors))). Instead `onValueChangeFinished` is used for sending the ***current local state*** to the viewmodel, as soon as we are done interacting.

Regarding detection of current interaction, we can make use of `InteractionSource`.

#### Working example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SliderDemo() {
    // In this demo, ViewModel updates its progress periodically from 0f..1f
    val viewModel by remember { mutableStateOf(SliderDemoViewModel()) }


    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {

        // local slider value state
        var sliderValueRaw by remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.progress) }

        // getting current interaction with slider - are we pressing or dragging?
        val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
        val isDragged by interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()
        val isInteracting = isPressed || isDragged

        // calculating actual slider value to display
        // depending on wether we are interacting or not
        // using either the local value, or the ViewModels / server one
        val sliderValue by derivedStateOf {
            if (isInteracting) {
                sliderValueRaw
            } else {
                viewModel.progress
            }
        }


        Slider(
            value = sliderValue, // using calculated sliderValue here from above
            onValueChange = {
                sliderValueRaw = it
            },
            onValueChangeFinished = {
                viewModel.updateProgress(sliderValue)
            },
            interactionSource = interactionSource
        )

        // Debug interaction info
        Text("isPressed: ${isPressed} | isDragged: ${isDragged}")
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this should not be necessary if you set the key in remember e.g.: ```var sliderValueRaw by remember(viewModel.progress) { mutableStateOf(viewModel.progress) }```

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of things going on here, so let's try to break it down.

The initial attempt where `onDimmerChanged` is called for every value change looks great!

Looking at the second attempt, creating a custom `Slider` component works, but there are a few issues.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LightView(
    channel: UiChannel,
    onDimmerChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    val sliderValue = channel....
    Slider(initialValue = sliderValue, valueSetter = onDimmerChanged)
}

@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { valueSetter(value) }
    )
}
```

Let's talk about what happens in the `Slider` composable here:

1. We remember the state with the `initialValue`
2. The `channel` value is updated, `LightView` gets recomposed, so does `Slider`
3. Since we remembered the state, it is still set to the previous `initialValue`

You're right with your thought about `remember` being the culprit here. When memorizing a value, it won't be updated when recomposing unless we tell Compose to. But without memorization (as seen in your third attempt), a state model will be created with every recomposition (`var value by mutableStateOf(initialValue)`) using the `initialValue`. Since a recomposition is triggered every time `value` changes, we will always pass the `initialValue` instead of the updated value to the Slider, causing it to never update by changes from within this Composable.
Instead, we want to pass `initialValue` as a key to `remember`, telling Compose to recalculate the value whenever the key changes.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { valueSetter(value) }
    )
}
```

You can probably also just pull the `Slider` into your `LightView`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LightView(
    channel: UiChannel,
    onDimmerChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    var value by remember(channel.sliderValue) { mutableStateOf(channel.sliderValue) }
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { onDimmerChanged(value) }
    )
}
```

---

Lastly, about the attempt that @commonsware suggested.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LightView(
    channel: UiChannel,
    onDimmerChanged: (Float) -> Unit
) {
    val sliderValue = channel....
    val sliderState = mutableStateOf(sliderValue)
    Slider(state = sliderState, valueSet = { onDimmerChanged(sliderState.value) })
}

@Composable
fun Slider(state: MutableState<Float>, valueSet: () -> Unit) {
    Slider(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { state.value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = valueSet
    )
}
```

This is another way of doing the same thing, but passing around `MutableState`s is an anti-pattern and should be avoided if possible. This is where state hoisting helps (what you were trying to do in the earlier attempts :))

---

Finally, about the `Slider`'s `onValueChangeFinished` using the wrong value.

> And it does not work either. When using drag and drop, sliderState is correctly updated, and onDimmerChanged() is called with the correct value. But for some reason, when tapping of the sliding (rather than sliding), valueSet is called and sliderState.value does not contain the correct value. I don't understand where this value comes from.

This is a bug in the `Slider` component. You can check this by looking at the output of this code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    val key = Random.nextInt()
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { 
            valueSetter(value)
            println("Callback invoked. Current key: $key")
        }
    )
}
```

Since `key` should change with every recomposition, you can see that the `onValueChangeFinished` callback holds a reference to an older composition (hope I put that right). So you weren't going crazy, it's not your fault :)

Hope that helped clear things up a bit!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!
I could not fix it even with it. I created a bug and a reproduction project https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181415195

Comment: setting the key for remember solved the problem: remember(key)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I can reproduce your issue as well. I answered in the bug topic, but I'll copy-paste it here so other people can fix it if they're in a rush. This solution sadly involves copying the whole Slider class.

The problem is that the drag and click modifiers use different Position instances, although they should always be the same (as Position is being created inside of remember).

The issue is with the pointer input modifier.

```
  val press = if (enabled) {
            Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {...}
```

Change the `Modifier.pointerInput()` to accept any other subject different than Unit so your `Position` instance in that Modifier is always up to date and updated when `Position` gets recreated. For example, you can change it to `Modifier.pointerInput(valueRange)`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem. As jossiwolf pointed out, using the progress as a `key` for the `remember{}` is necessary to ensure that the Slider progress is updated after recomposition.

I had an additional issue though, where, if I updated the progress mid-seek, the Slider would recompose, and the thumb would revert back to its old position.

To work around this, I'm using a temporary slider position, which is only used while a drag is in progress:

```
@Composable
fun MySlider(
    progress: Float,
    onSeek: (progress: Float) -> Unit,
) {
    val sliderPosition = remember(progress) { mutableStateOf(progress) }
    val tempSliderPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(progress) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isDragged = interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()

    Slider(
        value = if (isDragged.value) tempSliderPosition.value else sliderPosition.value,
        onValueChange = { progress ->
            sliderPosition.value = progress
            tempSliderPosition.value = progress
        },
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            sliderPosition.value = tempSliderPosition.value
            onSeek(tempSliderPosition.value)
        },
        interactionSource = interactionSource
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've elaborated on Steffen's answer a bit so it is possible to update the "external" "viewModel" value even while the user is currently dragging the slider (as there are many use cases when that is required).

The usage is the same as the compose "native" Slider, with the exception that the `onValueChangeFinished` parameter now accepts the finishing float value.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.collectIsDraggedAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.collectIsPressedAsState
import androidx.compose.material.Slider
import androidx.compose.material.SliderColors
import androidx.compose.material.SliderDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

/**
 * "Wrapper" around the Slider solving the issue of overwriting values during drag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386039/jetpack-compose-react-to-slider-changed-value.
 * Use as normal Slider and feel free to update the underlying value in the onValueChange method.
 */
@Composable
fun ComposeSlider(
        value: Float,
        onValueChange: (Float) -> Unit,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        enabled: Boolean = true,
        valueRange: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float> = 0f..1f,
        steps: Int = 0,
        onValueChangeFinished: ((Float) -> Unit)? = null,
        interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
        colors: SliderColors = SliderDefaults.colors()
) {
    // local slider value state with default value (from the "external" source)
    var sliderValueRaw by remember { mutableStateOf(value) }

    // getting current interaction with slider - are we pressing or dragging?
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val isDragged by interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()
    val isInteracting = isPressed || isDragged

    // calculating actual slider value to display depending on whether we are interacting or not
    // using either the local value, or the provided one
    val determinedValueToShow by remember(isInteracting, sliderValueRaw, value) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (isInteracting) {
                sliderValueRaw
            } else {
                value
            }
        }
    }

    Slider(
        value = determinedValueToShow,
        onValueChange = {
            sliderValueRaw = it
            onValueChange.invoke(it)
        },
        modifier = modifier,
        enabled = enabled,
        valueRange = valueRange,
        steps = steps,
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            onValueChangeFinished?.invoke(sliderValueRaw)
        },
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        colors = colors
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there are two things at play here.

1. the Server value
2. the Slider onChanged value.

your original idea is there. Using "remember" will update the slider changes.

```
@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    Slider(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { valueSetter(value) }
    )
}
```

This will update any changes done by the slider, but not the server.
The next thing you need is to add a LaunchEffect to update changes from the server

your final codes will look something like this: -

```
@Composable
fun Slider(initialValue: Float, valueSetter: (Float) -> Unit) {

    //remember change in slider values.
    var sliderValue by remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    Slider(
        value = sliderValue ,
        onValueChange = { sliderValue = it },
        onValueChangeFinished = { valueSetter(sliderValue ) }
    )

    //listen for changes in "initialValue" (the server value)
    LaunchedEffect (initialValue) {
        //slider jumps to new location everytime server value is changed. 
        sliderValue = initialValue
    }
}
```