Jetpack Compose RangeSlider crash for discrete values
I'm trying to use a RangeSlider to be able to select discrete values. The current data set I'm using comes from our backend with values in 15..50. It mostly works, except that two values on the slider end up having extremely precise decimal places, and it seems to be causing a crash when both endpoints are set to either one of those values.
Here is the current code:
// range is a value from the backend which can be different types, when it is a number Gson deserializes it as a double
val inputRange = (range.minValue as Double).toFloat()..(range.maxValue as Double).toFloat()

            val sliderState = remember {
                RangeSliderState(
                    activeRangeStart = inputRange.start,
                    activeRangeEnd = inputRange.endInclusive,
                    steps = (inputRange.endInclusive - inputRange.start).toInt() - 1,
                    valueRange =  inputRange,
                    onValueChangeFinished = {}
                )
            }

            val startInteractionSource = remember {
                MutableInteractionSource()
            }
            val endInteractionSource = remember {
                MutableInteractionSource()
            }

            androidx.compose.material3.RangeSlider(
                state = sliderState,
                startInteractionSource = startInteractionSource,
                endInteractionSource = endInteractionSource,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                startThumb = {
                    Label(
                        label = {
                            PlainTooltip {
                                Text(
                                    text = it.activeRangeStart.toString(),
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
                                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        interactionSource = startInteractionSource,
                        isPersistent = true
                    ) {
                        SliderDefaults.Thumb(interactionSource = startInteractionSource)
                    }
                },
                endThumb = {
                    Label(
                        label = {
                            PlainTooltip {
                                Text(
                                    text = sliderState.activeRangeEnd.toString(),
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
                                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        interactionSource = endInteractionSource,
                        isPersistent = true
                    ) {
                        SliderDefaults.Thumb(interactionSource = endInteractionSource)
                    }
                }
            )

Most points on the slider are fine and can be represented as whole numbers
Two points are not whole numbers
When both thumbs end up on one of the non whole number, there is a crash
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: start(673.12866) must be <= endInclusive(673.12854)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.SliderKt.SliderRange(Slider.kt:2121)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.RangeSliderState.onDrag$material3_release(Slider.kt:1991)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.RangeSliderLogic.captureThumb(Slider.kt:1575)

Is there a way to ensure all points are whole numbers to prevent this crash? Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?
I've tried converting numbers to ints before making them floats, manually setting the start and end values to ints when a new point is chosen, changing orders of operation. The expectation is that the numbers should divide evenly and not cause crashes.

I remember having a really similar problem, but it probably was with material2 RangeSlider, try checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386039/jetpack-compose-react-to-slider-changed-value
and round the values once they are changed

@JustSightseeing rounding the values for display is not a problem I actually started with that. This seems to be an internal issue with validating the range or calculating a position

Might be caused by a rounding error because floats have only a precision of 6 to 7 digits (the decimal separator doesn't matter): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#floating-point-types. Try multiplying the inputRange values by 100 to test if the problem persists.
